# CSRF exempt on REST View

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, csrf, django-csrf

I am serving an API which will be accessible with a small sensor sending a POST request with data. This sensor has a limited software, and I want to disable the CSRF protection on my API view.

So I've added the decorator:

```
url(
        regex=r'^beacons/$',
        view=csrf_exempt(ScanListCreateAPIView.as_view()),
        name='beacons'
    ),
```

Unfortunately, when I perform a POST with my sensor, I still get a 403 error:

```
<h1>Forbidden <span>(403)</span></h1>
  <p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>

  <p>You are seeing this message because this HTTPS site requires a 'Referer
   header' to be sent by your Web browser, but none was sent
. This header is
   required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being
   hijacked by third parties.</p>

  <p>If you have configured your browser to disable 'Referer' headers, please
   re-enable them, at least for this site, or for HTTPS connections, or for
   'same-origin' requests.</p>
```

I've try to add a "Referer: " null header in my POST request, but I still have a 403 response, mentionning that CSRF failed.

My request is:

```
POST /api/beacons HTTP/1.1
Host: vincent.pythonanywhere.com
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; esp8266 Lua; Windows NT 5.1)
Content-Length: 597

{"beacon":"aaa"," ...
```

The same request passed throught curl is working ok, with a 201 response.

Comment: DRF does its own CSRF stuff, it's hardcoded to be enabled when using `SessionAuthentication`, and disabled otherwise. You can switch to a different authentication mechanism.

Comment: I've tried with 'authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication,)' in my view, no change

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to diable CSRF:

1- As DRF does its own csrf with SessionAuth, you have to specify in the view:

```
authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication,)
```

2- Then I don't know exacly why, but `view=csrf_exempt(ScanListCreateAPIView.as_view()),` in urls doesn't work. Instead, use the braces mixin:

```
from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin, CsrfExemptMixin
class ScanListCreateAPIView(ListCreateAPIView, CsrfExemptMixin):
    authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication,)
```